# Android asset folder not able to load css file?

Tags: android, url, webview, assets

I am not able to load the local css file in my asset folder. But the error shows below and web view is not load the css file.

```
Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/css/mims.css
```

Comment: u can use relative url other than specific ur

Comment: Can u show your code??

Comment: StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", sb.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8", null);